# Оборот с предлогом "кроме" со значением включения

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги

Согласно Лопатину, такие обороты нужно выделять независимо от их значения включения или исключения. Но все же хочу уточнить, требуется ли здесь выделение?

Все большую популярность приобретают комбинированные регуляторы давления в моноблочном исполнении, в конструкцию которых, кроме самого регулятора давления, интегрированы также ПЗК и ПСК.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае предлог "кроме" имеет значение: "исключая", "не считая чего-либо". В этом случае предлог "кроме" всегда выделяется запятой. Запятые могут не ставиться (***являлось факультативном.***  ***прим.*** - мое), если предлог "кроме" имеет значение "дополнительно", "вдобавок к чему-либо". Лопатин упорядочил правило, согласно которому, предлог "кроме" выделяется запятой и в последнем значении  - включения.

Дополнение

Запятые могут не ставиться, если предлог «кроме» имеет значение ***«дополнительно, вдобавок к чему-либо».******Кроме*** школ наши поляки могли бы всё вести там по-своему, да не ведут. Н. Лесков, Город Краков. И вдруг Федя понял, что кроме этого светлого чувства в его душе рождается что-то похожее на неприязнь.****Однако и при таком значении предлога постановка запятых возможна.****
***Кроме*** радиоуправляемого ликвидатора***,*** манекен снабжён встроенным напоминателем о смерти – звоночком, который включится одновременно с началом работы электропилы. В. Пелевин, Встроенный напоминатель. ***( Запятание трудных слов, Грамота.ру).***

Answer (score 0):

Согласно Розенталю здесь значение включения: интегрированы и регулятор, и ПЗК, и ПСК. По старой норме запятые не нужны.

ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ для Сержа

Здесь значение включения. Ср.: Вызывают и остальных кроме тебя (и тебя вызывают, и остальных - включение). Вызывают и остальных, кроме тебя (остальных вызывают, а тебя нет - исключение). И у Розенталя нет факультативного обособления оборота, у него обособление четко зависит от смысла, просто смысл у одной фразы может быть разный. Не надо подставлять "исключая" и "не считая" - они не проверочные в данном случае. Надо оценивать логическое множество и смотреть, входят в него все элементы или только некоторые: в конструкцию входят регулятор, ПЗК и ПСК - значение включения.

Comment: Я бы так не сказал. Главный смысл: не считая регулятора давления Т.к. предлог "кроме" относится к этим словам, а не к и ПЗК, и ПСК. Т.е. смысл таков: в конструкцию которых, кроме самого регулятора давления( не считая регулятора давления)интегрированы также ПЗК и ПСК. К тому же и по Розенталю оборот "кроме" со значением "включения" может обособляться факультативно.

Comment: Тат, именно, что факультативно. Я привел правило в дополнении.

Comment: Серж, так это же не Розенталь. Это современное правило. По нему оборот с "кроме" всегда обособляется, невзирая на значение. А то, что они для различения значения советуют добавлять "исключая, не считая", - бред какой-то. Это не работает. Ср.: В комнате кроме меня Петя и Маша. Это "не считая меня" или "вдобавок ко мне"? ПАС: "В настоящее время различия в значениях оборотов со словом кроме не сказываются на пунктуации: и в том и в другом случае предусмотрено выделение запятыми. Однако в прошлом обороты со значением включения знаками препинания не выделялись".

Comment: Кстати, ПАС не советует подставлять какие-то проверочные слова для различения значений - видимо, как раз потому, что они не работают.

Comment: Тат, на грамоте представлены правила 1956г.

Comment: Да, я согласен с ПАС. Во многих случаях трудно определить значение включения-исключения.